# Select more than one item in layered navigation (multiple select/checkboxes)

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, product-list

How do you convert the standard layered navigation to use checkboxes or multiple select inputs for attributes of type **dropdown** or **multiselect**?

For example if a user selects **blue** and **red** for the color attribute, the layered navigation shows all items matching either blue **OR** red.

[**<strike>See example in toolbar on this page:</strike>**](http://tinyurl.com/d679bbe)

Comment: How did you go with this one? What did you decide to use?

Comment: @jharrison.au.. Well i have changed select drop down into COLOR SWITCHER and SIZE. Its not multiple yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many extensions out there that will give you this functionality (search for "enhanced layered navigation"). I have tried all of the extensions listed below but [my favourite is by Ecommerce Team](http://ecommerce-team.com/seo-layered-navigation.html) - I like it for its minimalistic nature, it doesn't try to do too much but is very powerful and works well out of the box. It also has support for color swatches like you described.

Some others in no particular order:

1. http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html
2. http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_layered_navigation_pro.html
3. http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus
4. http://www.gomage.com/extensions/gomage-advanced-navigation.html

Be aware these may cause conflicts with other third party modules.

---

If you are mainly looking to do this with color swatches I suggest you check out [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pre-select-colors-plus-swatches.html) by Chad Morgan.

---

Here's an [article by Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/) about keeping the unused filters visible.

---

If you're looking to code this yourself then I think the answer to your question might be too long for this forum. I don't have a link to a blog post/tutorial teaching you how to do this but I suggest starting with extending the layered navigation blocks.

Comment: I've used the Amasty module and would recommend checking it out. The Aitoc module, however, I would not touch with a 10' pole... or any of their modules for that matter.

Comment: The Amasty module will not work with any custom attributes which use a source backed by a custom eav model. This was an issue for us since our attributes are populated via external api.

Answer (score 9):

If you are only interested in converting default layered navigation to check boxes the solution is very easy and placing it here.

Edit the code of `app/design/frontend/ourpackage/ourtheme/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` file as follows:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <form>
                <span class="check-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onclick='window.location.assign("<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>")'/>
                </span>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
            </form>
        <?php else: ?>
            <form>
                <span class="check-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onclick='window.location.assign("<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>")'/>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                        <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

The solution is improved version of [this](http://sarathlal.com/replace-filter-links-in-layered-navigation-with-checkbox-magento/). So the credit goes to this person as well.