# Show Selected (active) Category Filter Attributes

Tags: filter, collection-filtering, filterable-attributes

I have updated the filters to show as a dropdown menu, rather than an . I updated template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml to be:

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <option  selected ="selected"><?php echo $this->__('sshhh') ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

**Problem:** The filter disappears once selected and is added to the 'Currently Shopping By' section

**Objective:** I'd like the filter dropdown to persist, even when one of the filter items has been selected. (I'd also like the dropdown to automatically pre-select whichever attribute filter is currently active, if any. But I can do this bit, I think)

**Help:** How do I keep a filter displayed, even when one of the filter items is selected? I've traced the route back to the core files, but at no point does it seem to 'hide' selected/active filters, it seems.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty extensions that do this.

My favourite is [ManaDev Multiple Select In Layered Navigation (Filters)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html)
But there are others.

There is a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/select-more-than-one-item-in-layered-navigation-multiple-select-checkboxes)

Both answers can provide info on your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as answer. It will take some customisation of the ManaDev extension to achieve what I need, but should hopefully work. Ideally, I'd just like to be able to say in the code 'display filters, even if one of the filter attributes is selected', this would solve all my problems, and would save me from having to install an extension, most of which will not be used. Many thanks

Comment: I'm using mana filter but the category disappears after selecting it

Comment: I'm not a Manadev expert or affiliated with them. 
Plus I don't know anything about your setup... Mage ver, Mana ver etc.
But,..... 
If you click on a subcategory you end up in this category ... so it should 'disappear', this is how it works. Try using layered navigation filters instead of categories.